# Simulators for BLE(Bluetooth Lowe energy)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Any simulator available to test BLE(Bluetooth Lowe energy) mobile applications instead of testing with real BLE device?

Comment: Raspberry PI + BLENO, Android + BLETool

Comment: @MikePetrichenko  i need a stub which should behave like a BLE device

Comment: Raspberry PI + BLENO, Android + BLETool

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can check BLE Peripheral Simulator available in Play Store.